# Multiple double quotes and back slashes throwing SQL error: "The column delimiter for column was not found"

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

How can I import data from a 2 GB CSV to microsoft SQL Server 2016 when column 2 in CSV has a text: "Fixed in \"next\"" in some rows? The data looks like this

```
17690,2491303,"0 - Backlog"
17695,4070890,"won't run"
17696,3758423,"levels"
17697,408688,"support"
17698,3516,"Fixed in \"next\""
17700,3516,"Rangeslider"
17704,3516,"Fixed in \"next\""
```

I used this [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5joUx.jpg)

However, I am getting the error:

```
- Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202055: Data Flow Task 1: The column delimiter for column "Column 2" was not found.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Answer (score 0):

`{LF}` stands for `line-feed`. which typically follows a `{CR}` (carriage return). it basically means that the last column is separated by a new line, like when hitting the enter/return key.

I'm guessing that `{LF}` alone is not the delimiter. I would try `{CR}{LF}` together but check the following link for more available options.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180239.aspx

Sharing a sample of the text file will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I tried {LF}, {CR}, as well as {CR}{LF}. But, I am still getting that error!

Comment: @Geet - can you share a couple of lines from the text file?

Comment: I have just provided few lines from my CSV file.

Comment: @Geet - I pasted what you sent me in notepad++ and the **LINE** delimiter is indeed `CRLF`. there doesn't seem to be a delimiter for the last column though. have you tried leaving the column2 delimiter blank?

Comment: No, let me try that.

Comment: There don't seem to be any blank option for the column delimiter!? How can I choose blank, then?

Comment: @Geet - not sure. I can't test it right now. can you try setting {CR}{LF} and go to the last line of the file and make sure that you hit enter and save? in the sample you sent me the last line is missing the delimiter. maybe that causes the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123671/discussion-between-ted-and-geet).

Comment: Hi was there any solution to this ?